# solve a nonlinear model with DICOPT solver in Pyomo

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, neos-server

How can I solve a nonlinear model with DICOPT solver in Pyomo?
Is this possible to use DICOPT solver through Neos for Pyomo?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the Neos server only supports a small number of solvers through Pyomo. I may consider installing 'gams' with at least a demo license and call DICOPT from gams from Pyomo.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use DICOPT solver in Pyomo, not supported. However, if your model is written in Pyomo then you can save it in gams format using `model.write('mymodel.gms')` then upload it to NEOS. Or open your model in GAMS Studio, select GAMS > Run NEOS - Short from the menu to automatically establish a connection with NEOS. In that case you can use GAMS demo without paying any license fees.